# How do I enter the BIOS setup on an HP P6210T

Tags: boot, laptop, bios

I hit every Function key, but that just got me into the "Recovery Manager".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Entering the BIOS Setup utility

- Turn off the computer and wait five seconds.
- Turn on the computer.
- When the first screen displays, immediately press the F10 key if your computer was built in 2006 or later (came with Vista). Press the F1 key if your computer was built before 2006 (XP or earlier). Press the key once every second until a BIOS Setup utility screen opens.
- Use the keyboard to move through the menus.

[Source](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=bph07110&dlc=en&lc=en&cc=us)

I hope it'll help.