# Assess BIOS on HP Pavilion xt966

Tags: bios

I'm attempting to change the boot device priority on a older HP. When it starts up it flashes a HP splash screen then just goes black with a blinking caret.

I tried the suggestion of leaving it off for 5 sec then [hitting F1. No dice.](https://superuser.com/questions/63534/how-do-i-enter-the-bios-setup-on-an-hp-p6210t)

I'm using a USB keyboard. I might grab a PS2 and give it a go. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F2 and Esc are also commonly used on computers to get into the BIOS. (You might also try del but i'm not sure if that'll work)

I'd definitley suggest going for the PS2 keyboard. A lot of older computers don't work with USB when they boot.

Comment: Yeah no dice there. This is just odd.

Comment: The PS2 Keyboard did the trick.

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Comment: Now to solve the acpi_tz0: _TMP issue in BSD... ;)